# Eliminating the extra copy when using getline + istringstream to parse cin inputs?

Tags: c++, csv, stream, stringstream, istringstream

As my example, I am reading input in a CSV  format. I need to take a line as input and then parse it.

#### Example

The standard suggestion for parsing lines of `std::cin` inputs looks like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string inp;
    std::getline(std::cin, inp);

    std::istringstream inp_stream{ inp };

    std::string word_1;
    std::string word_2;
    std::string word_3;

    std::getline(inp_stream, word_1, ',');
    std::getline(inp_stream, word_2, ',');
    std::getline(inp_stream, word_3);

    std::cout << word_1 << "\n";
    std::cout << word_2 << "\n";
    std::cout << word_3;
}
```

The input `hello,stack,overflow` gives output

```
hello
stack
overflow
```

as expected.

#### The Problem

My problem with this method is that it seems to require an unnecessary copy of the input string. The string is copied from the input buffer to `inp` and copied again from `inp` to `inp_stream`. I'm sure this second copy is necessary to support the `istringstream` functionality, but it seems unnecessary to put the line in a `std::string` in the first place.

It would be nice if I could simply copy the input from the buffer to the `istringstream`. Can I eliminate the extra copy?

#### A Bad Solution

One bad solution would be to skip the `istringstream` by doing the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string word_1;
    std::string word_2;
    std::string word_3;

    std::getline(std::cin, word_1, ',');
    std::getline(std::cin, word_2, ',');
    std::getline(std::cin, word_3);

    std::cout << word_1 << "\n";
    std::cout << word_2 << "\n";
    std::cout << word_3;
}
```

Input

```
I am,

a
user,
```

gives output

```
I am


a
user
```

As you can see, the input was not in CSV format.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to std::move std::string into std::stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229670/is-there-a-way-to-stdmove-stdstring-into-stdstringstream)

Comment: Prior to C++20, I'm sure you can find a 3rd party (or write your own) `std::streambuf` that just reads from the `std::string` directly instead of making a copy of its data. Then you can use that `streambuf` with `std::istream` directly, rather than using `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @DrewDormann C++20

Comment: @user589321 you're in luck then.  The link in my last comment is a duplicate, with a working C++20 solution.

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks. I had actually found that question and, after reading the accepted answer, didn't consider that the standard might have changed.